# Auto adjust css depending on a percentage

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am building an online editor which allows user to resize canvas.

I am using currently using Jquery window resize function to detect when the user resizes the canvas then let Jquery calculate reduce percentage (Resized Height / Original Page Height).

Then I resize propreties like (padding, font-size, top, left ...) and put them as inline texts.

For example Original div :

```
<div style="font-size: 22px; width: 290px; left: 36px; bottom: 16px; position:absolute"> Text </div>
```

If user reduce window to 50% of original size it changes to

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; width: 145px; left: 18px; bottom: 8px; position:absolute"> Text </div>
```

It works fine ( Despite some minor jquery calculations floating). However when the user clicks render I let the jquery get the current inline style propreties and post them to rendering server.

The issue is I can't manage return the elements to their original size on server side ( I have the multiplication percentage ) My rendering backend performs on PHP and I also post the ratio percentage to get back to original size.

Posted parameter is stored into variable $css and it's something like this

```
font-size: 11px; width: 145px; left: 18px; bottom: 8px; position:absolute
```

How can I change these resized version and make them bigger by 200%

```
font-size: 22px; width: 290px; left: 36px; bottom: 16px; position:absolute
```

Either on php side or jquery side before posting would do the job !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO you need to ise media queries https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: @Francesco Media queries aren't an option because the canvas size is dynamic and there is no fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

```
font-size: 2vw; width: 21.3vw; left: 3vw; bottom: 3vw; position: absolute;
```

Please try this css. it's will this css auto set on window width.